# How to bypass route path filtering (for ping)?

Tags: linux, routing, monitoring

I know asymmetric is **wrong** and I do not want to use it. But on the other hand I have Linux server having multiple interfaces (prod, backup, interconnect) and I want to monitor them all - via ping for example.

But I can not make our monitoring SW to have interface in every VLAN. So the source IP for the ping packet is only one, and monitoring works only for the prod server's interface.

AFAIK: Windows 2012 has feature, can bypass this *limitation*, but I can not find any reasonable solution for Linux. 
For example I would like to avoid something like double NAT for ping packets entering and leaving backup VLAN.

Answer (score 2):

bypasing rp filtering whould only permit You to test incomming connectivity (returning packets will be always routed with main interface).
You can disable rp_filtering in sysctl for optons list please see
`sysctl -a|grep rp_filter`

Cleanest approach might be to create additional routing tables for all links with there's own default gateways, and route all traffic form backup and other if's ips with dedicated routing tables having default route in those networks.

http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html -
[4.2.1. Split access]